# JQuery Shopping Basket

Tags: javascript, image

I want to implement kind of a shopping basket. Idea is that the user is able to drop certain draggable images into a specific area and than the parent of the image changes to the div of the cart.

Base looks like this:

```
 <div id="box">

      <div id="basketContainer"></div>


      <img src="./imgTrue.jpg" class="toggleImage"></img>

    </div>
```

And here is what I tried:

```
$('#basketContainer').droppable({
        drop:function(e,source){
            $(source).appendTo('#basketContainer');

        }
      });
```

And this is what I got:

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: what is source here ?

Comment: Its the image element

Comment: can you simply console.log source and then copy that string and pass it to $(source). What do you get ?

Comment: If I log $(source) than it seems to return a draggable item. I tried using $(source.draggable) for appending but that does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opPReb

You need to have at least one draggable item and another droppable container to carry out that behavior. You should change your selector to get an element instead or array of elements.

`$(source.draggable[0]).appendTo(this);`

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="basketContainer"></div>
    <img id="draggable" src="https://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-
       content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery-ui.png" class="toggleImage">
    </img>
</div>

#draggable {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

#basketContainer { 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 300px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px; 
    background: red;
}

$('#draggable').draggable();
$('#basketContainer').droppable({
    drop:function(e,source){
        $(source.draggable[0]).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok I solved that. I got classes linked to the dragged image which contain a reference to an image element. How would I check if this is equal to source.draggable[0]

Comment: If the dragged image has an id still attached to it. it must be same. Every Id is unique.

You are not comparing two different DOM elements. Its the same that was dropped in a different container.

Comment: The images are dynamically generated and do not have an ID. I solved it like this:  $(this.img).is($(el));

Comment: well great then (,")

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logged element you would need to use $(source.draggable[0]) to get at the element you are trying append.